# Underlying data structure for QSortFilterProxyModel in Qt 5 and PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qsortfilterproxymodel

What is the underlying data structure used by Qt5 and PyQt for filtering and sorting with the `QSortFilterProxyModel` object?

This question came to me when I saw how slow my computer was to sort and filter a bunch of 500.000 rows with my PyQt project compare to Excel. I don't mean that it should be faster than Excel but at least approaching.

The set of data used for the comparaison is the same and the main goal of the question is to know if I should implement my own data structure over the `QSortFilterModel` if I want better performance.

Comment: If you want to know how it works, read the [source code](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.5/5.5.1/single/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1.zip.mirrorlist). The other questions are impossible to answer without seeing an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks but I wanted to avoid a source code reading :) I guess it won't be possible otherwise. I expect to find an array but lets wait and see.

Comment: I doubt that reading the qt sources is going to help you much. It would be far more productive to write a simplified test case that allows other people to try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: The test doesn't need to hook a model up to a database, because the sorting doesn't query it, right? The bottleneck is just the model and its proxy. But perhaps more to the point: is there some good reason why you are not using a [QSqlTableModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsqltablemodel.html)?

Comment: I could try to do so. But the project involves querying a database, sending the data into a QStandardItemModel, initiating a QTableView, several comboboxes to sort data through multiple columns, and finally sorting or filter the datas through a QSortFilterModel. By reading the source code, it seems that the QSortFilterProxyModel maps all the datas through each row and each column to index it each time a sort is done cause it has to refer to the original source model to be able to process a comparison (the QStandardItemModel). So, I guess the complexity is between linear and quadratic.

Comment: You are right, the sorting doesn't query the database. In fact, I did not want to use a QSqlTableModel cause I wanted to separate the view part from the model part of my project and reuse my sub class of QTableView for other sources. In other words, I didn't want to be completely stuck by Qt.

Comment: I don't get it. A `QSqlTableModel` **is** separate from its view(s). And how could you re-use a `QTableView` sub-class outside of Qt? Anyway, it seems the price you pay for trying to re-invent the wheel is slower wheels...

Comment: In a precedent project, I have develop a package to query a database. The project wasn't using any GUI. Now I want to reuse this package has much as I possible and build something fun with Python. This is what I call the model part of my project. For me Qt is just a GUI and should not overpass this role in my project (the view part).

Comment: You say all that, and yet you are using the ready-made `QStandardItemModel` class rather than a custom sub-class of `QAbstractTableModel` (which could talk directly to your database backend). If you do everything through proxies of one kind or another, it seems inevitable that there will be some significant performance costs along the way.